# Find a date between start_date and end_date

Tags: mysql

I have a table of events with a recorded start and end time. I want to find all events that occur on a specific date. Some events started a year ago and some will continue farther ahead.

I would like to be able to pick for example May 20, 2010 and find all events occurring on that date.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable 
  WHERE start_date >= '2010-01-01' AND end_date <= '2010-06-30'
```

This query will return all dates where start_date is on or after 1st Jan, 2010, and end_date is on or before 30th June, 2010.

Comment: That will give me all events between those dates, however, some of those events will have ended say between February and May of 2010, and I wouldn't want expired events to show.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from TableName
where '2010-05-20' >= start_date and '2010-05-20' <= end_date
```

This will give you all events that occur on a specific date, even if the start or send dates are on different days.

Comment: This doesn't produce any records.

Answer (score 2):

Try...

```
WHERE (((MONTH(start_date) >= MONTH(NOW())) && (MONTH(end_date) <= MONTH(NOW()))) && YEAR(start_date) >= YEAR(NOW()))
```

That would get you anything from 3/2010.

Or..

```
WHERE ((MONTH(start_date) >= MONTH(NOW())) && YEAR(start_date) >= YEAR(NOW())))
```

Would get you events after 3/2010 into the future, and nothing before that.

Or..

```
WHERE (start_date_var) BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

Simply, where (passed value) is between any event start and end date.

These should produce results. It depends on how you are executing the query. Are you accepting form/url arguments to change dates?

It's confusing though that you want to have all dates that are not expired, yet also want dates that occurred on a specific date. Where are you getting start_date from?

Comment: This is a link to a page that has a calendar at the bottom of it that is similar to mine:  http://www.torontolife.com.  

I hope someone can post an idea on how to work this out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have input parameters named @start_date and @end_date, and you want to find any event that overlaps that range:

```
select *
  from TableName
 where @start_date between start_date and end_date
    or @end_date between start_date and end_date
```

Comment: My code on the search page is as follows:

$SearchResult=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE start_date >= '$start_date' and end_date <= '$end_date'") or die(mysql_error());

And on the calendar page I have:

$cal->addEvent('', 2010, 3, 27, 'search/eventSearch.php?start_date=2010-03-27&amp;end_date=2010-03-27');

I have a feeling I am doing something completely wrong.  I hope someone can help me.  Please.

Comment: OK, given two inputs, see changes above. You might be able to use $start_date rather than @start_date, depending on your php.ini.

Comment: This problem has been solved.  I had an error on the search page irrelevant to what I have posted.  Thank you for your help.